# R Create Function To Run Many Hypothesis Tests

Tags: r, function, lapply

```
data = data.frame(group1 = sample(1:4, r = T, size = 10000),
                  group2 = sample(1:2, r = T, size = 10000),
                cat = sample(0:1, r = T, size = 10000),
                fox = sample(0:1, r = T, size = 10000),
                dog = sample(0:1, r = T, size = 10000),
                rabbit = sample(0:1, r = T, size = 10000),
                bunny = sample(0:1, r = T, size = 10000))
```

What if you want to run a lot of chi-squared tests such that:
You want to compare all VAR variables like this, separately for each VAR, and store into dataframe:

```
> group1 = 1 and group2 = 1 VERSUS group1 = 2 and group2 = 1
> 
> group1 = 1 and group2 = 1 VERSUS group1 = 3 and group2 = 1
> 
> group1 = 1 and group2 = 1 VERSUS group1 = 4 and group2 = 1
> 
> group1 = 1 and group2 = 0 VERSUS group1 = 2 and group2 = 0
> 
> group1 = 1 and group2 = 0 VERSUS group1 = 3 and group2 = 0
> 
> group1 = 1 and group2 = 0 VERSUS group1 = 4 and group2 = 0
```

This is what I try to do,

```
myfunction = function(data, GROUP1, GROUP2, variables){
data %>% filter(data, group1 = GROUP1, group2 = GROUP2)
mydata[] = chisq.test(table(data$GROUP1, data$GROUP2))$p.value
}
```

And it goes without saying, I have not gotten very far on it!
__ 
Desired output is something like this, and please be aware that all comparisons are made as describe as above so we don't need group1 == 1 since that's the comparison group. In other words p.val is the p.val for testing differences between the groups in the picture below and group1=1.

[image]

Comment: @Len Greski maybe you have a solution?

Comment: Could you show an example of your expected output?

Comment: I think you are confusing the difference between `=` and `==`. The first is assignment, the second is logical "equals".  Also, chi square involves two categorical variables. Run your analysis for a single Chi square and show us what that looks like. You are dividing your data into two groups based on group 1 and 2 values. That will bias any Chi Square analysis since you are analyzing the relationship between the same variables that you used to subset the data. Also you are defining two groups that do not have the same number of observations.

Comment: @Len Greski I updated with a sample

Comment: @akrun maybe you have an idea?